# How do I use Tensorflow JS with Minima / other Jekyll Themes?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, jekyll, tensorflow.js

I was wondering if there is a way to use Tensorflow JS with Minima. In theory, it seems possible (I need to add an HTML page basically). However, I'm not quite sure how I could add an HTML page to an existing setup. Any thoughts? I'm using Github Pages if it matters.

Comment: What do themes have to do with TensorFlow.js? Machine learning and style are on  two different levels?

Comment: @scai Yes, but I'm haven't been able to find any resources on adding an HTML page (which we need for TF JS) to an existing theme.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the answer you want but most Jekyll theme has a file embedded into the head of the HTML file, which is named `head.html`.

Minima has `head.html` in this directory.

https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html

By writing [the tag](https://js.tensorflow.org/setup/) to load the TensorFlow.js, you should be able to use TensorFlow.js from any page in your site.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this would be helpful to you.